# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer landscape frame

Tags: ios, swift

Hi i got a problem with AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, when i'm turning my phone to landscape, i'm losting a part of camera screen.

i'm putting some pictures.

When i'm in portrait mode

[image: When i'm in portrait mode]

When i switch to landscape mode
[image]

Back to portrait mode
[image]

Code:

```
func setupPreviewLayer(orientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation) {
    cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = orientation
    cameraPreviewLayer?.frame.size = self.view.frame.size
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
}
```

Transition ovveride:

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    captureSession.stopRunning()
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        setupPreviewLayer(orientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight)
        setupRunningCaptureSession()
    }
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
        setupPreviewLayer(orientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait)
        setupRunningCaptureSession()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in viewDidLoad

```
cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
//cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = orientation
cameraPreviewLayer?.frame.size = self.view.frame.size
self.view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
```

then add this code to viewController

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = view.frame
        if let cameraPreviewLayer = cameraPreviewLayer ,(cameraPreviewLayer.connection?.isVideoOrientationSupported)! {
            cameraPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.videoOrientation ?? .portrait
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that what was missing in willTransition is:
cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = view.frame

In addition I dont think it is useful to create an additional layer every time there is a rotation.
Here is below the code I am using

in ViewDidLoad()

```
  videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: camera.session)

  videoPreviewLayer!.frame = view.layer.bounds
  videoPreviewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill


  let statusBarOrientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
  videoPreviewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = statusBarOrientation.videoOrientation!

  view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
```

And in willTransition

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.videoPreviewLayer!.frame = self.view.frame

        let statusBarOrientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
        self.videoPreviewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = statusBarOrientation.videoOrientation ?? .portrait

}
```

Based on my tests on iOS 12.1, DispatchQueue is mandatory.
Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

The frame of your view is not yet updated when `willTransition(to:with:)` is callled. You should use `traitCollectionDidChange(_:)` instead:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    captureSession.stopRunning()
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        setupPreviewLayer(orientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight)
        setupRunningCaptureSession()
    }
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
        setupPreviewLayer(orientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait)
        setupRunningCaptureSession()
    }
}
```